# Eclipse Spring Tool Suite add dependencies using GUI after project creation

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Every time I start a new `Spring Boot` project - using *Spring Tool Suite* and now as *STS4* - through `Spring Starter Project` I can add dependencies using GUI like on the screenshot below.

[image: Adding dependencies in GUI]

It's very convenient to choose dependencies in GUI. But sometimes I forget to add some dependencies and have to add them to the `pom.xml` file manually.

Is it possible to add new dependencies using GUI the same way like during `Spring Starter Project` configuration after project creation?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you can. Right click on the pom of the generated project and choose `Spring -> Edit Starters` from the context-menu. It opens up the same dialog and lets you add additional dependencies.

You just need to take care of the correct Spring Boot version yourself, it isn't set automatically to the version that you chose when you created the project. It doesn't cause any huge trouble if you choose the wrong version, but spring starter modules might show up that aren't compatible with your project.

Comment: Any idea about for those using Gradle? There is no such option for build.gradle

Comment: No, there is no such feature for gradle build configs yet, but feel free to raise an enhancement request at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues

Comment: @MartinLippert Was it added for Gradle too? If not, pls let me know to create the respective issue.

Comment: @ManuelJordan We don't support Gradle based projects in the Add Starters wizard yet.